# Calling Server Side Scripting from JavaScript Not Working in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to call Server Side function using JavaScript . I m using PageMethod.
But Code is not working. Please tell Error in code Block.
I m using two JavaScript function onLoad. AJAX Script Manager PageMethod is also set to true.
My Server Side Function in not taking any value as input nor returning any value.

```
function GetData() {
    PageMethods.GetData(OnSuccess);
}
function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(response);
}
function GetOS() {
    console.log("rom");
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e) {
        var data = {},
            fdata = [],
            loc = $('<a>', { href: window.location })[0];
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i) {
            if (this.checked) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                    data[this.name] = [];
                }
                data[this.name].push(this.value);
            }
        });
        var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
        var fdata = key + "=" + data[key].join(',');
        $.post('/ajax-post-url/', fdata);
        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname + '?' + fdata);
        }
    });            
}        
window.addEventListener("load", GetOS, false);
window.addEventListener("load", GetData, false);
```

```csharp
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void GetData()
{
    if(Request.QueryString.ToString() != "")
    {
        System.Data.DataTable DT = new System.Data.DataTable();
        DT = BLL.GetProjectByLike(Request.QueryString["PSC"].ToString());
        if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = DT;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Data.DataTable DT = new System.Data.DataTable();
        DT = BLL.AdminSeeProjectIns();
        if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = DT;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you call the `Repeater1`, this is not exist on that call ! You can not have access to page controls call from javascript.

Comment: So how can i call Repeater1 from JavaScript. Or there is alternate to do this.

Comment: My Task is to get values from database to Repeater when value changes in Query String.

Comment: Please tell more specific @Aristos

Comment: Just warp your code with an UpdatePanel.... look for some tutorial about UpdatePanel on internet

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: I Wrapped My Code in update panel But it still not working ! @Aristos

Comment: what error did you get, do you made any debug ? did this works with out updatepanel with simple post back ?... I am sorry but I am not there to debug your code, you must do that for your self